# Get Ad Account Billing Payment Transactions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am looking to get the Billing Payment Transactions for each Ad Account under my Business Manager.

"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_{AD_ACCOUNT_ID}/transactions" Does not seem to be an active endpoint anymore.

Any recommendations?

"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_{AD_ACCOUNT_ID}/transactions" No longer active Endpoint. I don't see any available endpoint in the documentations, but I hope I am just missing something.

Comment: This is a Facebook support question, not a programming question. Off-topic here - see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)